# Linq Results into IEnumerable in ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to put my linq query results into view model but I keep getting an error. Linq query returns multiple rating results. I would like to put these multiple rating results in an IEnumerable.

> Error:    Cannot implicitly convert type Models.CustomerRating' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.CustomerRating>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Linq query

```
var data = from profile in _context.Customers
           join rating in _context.CustomerRating
                on profile.strUserID equals rating.strUserID into rt
           from subrating in rt.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where profile.strUserID == UserId
           select new { p = profile, r = subrating };
```

My view model:

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public CustomerProfile Customer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerProfile> CustomerProfiles { get; set; }
    public CustomerServices CustomerServices { get; set; }

    public FilterServicesViewModel FilterServices { get; set; }

    public CustomerRating Rating { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerRating> CustomerRating { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to the results of profile to be added to Customer and subrating to CustomerRating `IEnumerable`.

I have tried the following but I get an error:

```
foreach (var v in data)
{
    serviceProviderViewModel.Customer = v.p;
    serviceProviderViewModel.CustomerRating = v.r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new list and loop through your linq query results and add it to that list

```
    List<CustomerRating> RatingList = new List<CustomerRating>();
            foreach (var v in data)
            {
                serviceProviderViewModel.Customer = v.p;
                RatingList.Add(v.r); 
            }
            serviceProviderViewModel.CustomerRating = RatingList;
```